# Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento 2 EE 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, module, magento-enterprise-2

**Environment:**

Magneto EE 2.3.4
PHP 7.2.23-1
OS Ubuntu 16.04

**Error:**

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
>   Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid\Collection\Interceptor

**Situation:**

I am trying to add and admin Grid in Magento 2 Custom Module... It's working fine on `Developer Mode` but I am getting this error in `Production Mode`

Here is My Code Of `Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid\Collection.php`

```
<?PHP
use Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection as CustomCollection;

/**
 * Class Grid COllection
 */

class Collection extends CustomCollection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    private $_aggregations;

    private $storeManager;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,        
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory, 
            $logger, 
            $fetchStrategy, 
            $eventManager, 
            $storeManager, 
            $connection, 
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->_aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->_aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all ids for collection
     * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have Tried by removing `var/` and `generated/` folder and run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Did you get the answer? Why it is happening in 'developer' mode?

Comment: Yes I have inherited `Collection` from `CustomCollection` but in my `CustomCollection` there was no any  object as `StoreManagerInterface` so I removed in injected `StoreManagerInterface` class from `Collection` constructor and my issue was resolved

Comment: I am able to resolve my problem as well. But I am looking for answer on why it worked on 'developer' mode and why not worked in 'production' mode? Is it related to code compilation?